# Run minify after publish in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, web-deployment

Does anyone know of a good way to minify all js, css, etc. files as part of the publish process? I'm thinking, run a batch file that fires jmin? But not sure how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the .net [ClientDependancy Framework](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/) to do this

**Update**

You start out by defining paths to the directories which contain the resources to manage, something like this:

```
<CD:ClientDependencyLoader runat="server" id="Loader">
    <Paths>
      <CD:ClientDependencyPath Name="Styles" Path="~/css" />
      <CD:ClientDependencyPath Name="Scripts" Path="~/js" />
    </Paths>
</CD:ClientDependencyLoader>
```

You then specify the files to manage in JS or CSS includes:

```
<CD:JsInclude ID="baseScript" runat="server" FilePath="~/js/baseScript.js" Priority="0" />
```

Don't forget to register the control at the top of the file:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="ClientDependency.Core.Controls" Assembly="ClientDependency.Core" TagPrefix="CD"  %>
```

Comment: Looks interesting, the documentation isn't very clear though?! So do you simply add a link(dependancy) to the unminified css/js and then when debug="false" it will compress the css/js and update the resulting link/script reference?

Comment: I added some code from a project I used it on. It is by no means a complete representation of all configurations but should be enough to get you started :)